# Unsure about where to navigation code or which pattern to use with designing a website with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, design-patterns

Currently I am designing a website using asp.net 3.5, devexpress controls, SQL server.

There is quite a bit navigation involved in the site. e.g. there are multiple entry points the login page or there are wizard type of forms involved in the site. And I am not sure if I should code this navigation logic right in aspx pages or should I be creating another class or whole different layer for navigation. I have similar questions about other things as well. Like should I use a facade pattern...

Can any body recommend any articles or books which has reliable information about how can I code this so that the site/the web application will be maintainable, code will reliable, easy to read (all qualities of robust code).

I am not sure, if this is right platform to ask this question but I thought I should throw this question out - either somebody will mention books or will guide me to right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on same type of application in which
1)there were wizard type of forms
2)showing selective menu items as per the roles ( both horizontal and vertical menu to (1- n) levels
3) multiple entry points

We used xslt to generate the wizard or menu items in html and the metadata for navigation we either put in xml files or database . I know its a old way of doing things but the flexibility  we got was enormous. I can give more insight on above if you like the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to use .net user administration with the site?  You can configure some of the authentication using web.config files the assign access to certain pages through authentication.  A great resource I have used are the [tutorials on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms).  Here's a link on [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx).

Also, I would definitely look at Master Pages for the navigation component of the application.  There are some good tutorials on Master Pages on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***ASP.Net SiteMap Provider*** can do it. It is based on Provider Model Design Pattern. There are a lot of articles on internet.

In addition, you can implement Custom SiteMap Provider, if you want more complex navigation logic.